# jQuery("#wrapper").css({ opacity: 0.5 })

Tags: jquery, css, opacity

I just applied a opacity to a `#wrapper` `div` with a solid color:

```
jQuery("#wrapper").css({ opacity: 0.5 })
```

This works nicely, but I don't want their children `div`s to inherit the opacity. How do I avoid this behavior without using PNG transparency hacks?

Comment: The short answer is you can't. You will have to place the contents in a different container.

Comment: If you want a little bit of transparency on the background of the #wrapper, try use rgba() instead of solid color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Opacity is always inherited by descendant elements. There are no way to avoid it, and it isn't due to jQuery, but the way opacity works.

Answer (score 1):

Clone the element (and children) and get the offsets. Then in the original element, hide all the inner elements. Now set the opacity. With the cloned element, place it on top of the original element (using position and the offsets), but this time hide the background to the cloned element.